# Has the claim 'test error is greater than training error' analytically been proved?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction

'Test error is greater than training error' is generally admitted in the statistical learning field.

However, so far I couldn't find the analytic proof for this.

Note : I.I.D situation, i.e., no sampling bias allowed across the observations.

Does anyone know this?

Comment: It's not always true. So you have no chance to find a proof for this

Comment: Thanks, but that is the case biased to test error.

Comment: You seem certain that the case is biased to the test error. If you can determine with certainty (analytically), that any occurrence of the test error being lower than the train error, is due to bias, that is the prove you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but that claim is generally admitted as true even included in the famous textbooks(like T.E.L). Also, from my simulation and real data examinations, it seems to be true. If asymptotically handled, my conjecture is that test error is equal to training error. Any idea?